# How can i topologically sort 2D triangles and put in an array?

Tags: geometry, topology, jts-topology-suite, sorting

I have a set of 2D triangles in a Geometry array which together forms a
connected strip when placed them according to edge adjacency. However, in
the array they are not in topological order based on the edge adjacency. 
How can i topologically sort them and put in the array?

Comment: And what's the software you use? And it's version?

Comment: I use JTS library.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to perform a topological sort, where the triangles are
the nodes of the graph and the edge-adjacency provides the graph edges.
 Since you know the graph is a single line, the sort actually devolves into
finding a node with only one other adjacent triangle, and then traversing
the graph visiting all the other triangles in turn.

Comment: This is equivalent to a [standard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for topological sorting.

Comment: @whuber would this work for triangles covering a sphere? (Like for an Icosahedron?)

Comment: @Kirk No triangulation of an icosahedron would constitute a "strip." Although it takes some parsing to figure it out, this question concerns *only* a triangulation in which the (abstract) edge-adjacency graph is linear.  Whether or not they are on a sphere, a plane, or any other place is immaterial.  (So basically this question asks "how do I sort those triangles" and the answer here is "use a brute-force search to find a triangle at one end, then proceed from there." Because of the assumptions, there are no choices to be made and no more searching to do.)